# Error when installing uCommerce with Umbraco 7

Tags: installation, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I'm having issues when trying to install uCommerce into Umbraco 7.  I have tried installing via the online package and via a local package I downloaded from their website.  Both are failing with the same error message.

This is installing it on Umbraco 7.2.7 using uCommerce 6.8.2

```
2015-10-20 10:59:23,832 [114] ERROR Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - [P2760/T103/D30] An unhandled exception occurred
System.ArgumentException: The relative virtual path 'function sortCampaignItems(){
UmbClientMgr.openModalWindow('/umbraco/ucommerce/marketing/SortCampaignItems.aspx?id=' + UmbClientMgr.mainTree().getActionNode().nodeId, 'Sort',true,600,450);
}' is not allowed here.
   at System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options)
   at System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(String virtualPath, String applicationPath)
   at Umbraco.Core.IO.IOHelper.ResolveUrl(String virtualPath)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Umbraco.Web.Editors.BackOfficeController.GetLegacyActionJs(LegacyJsActionType type)
   at Umbraco.Web.Editors.BackOfficeController.Application()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Can anyone help with any suggestions of resolving this matter?  I've been at this for hours and don't seem be getting anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Jesper Nielsen via http://eureka.ucommerce.net/#!/question/1649/Error-when-installing-uCommerce-with-Umbraco-7

Hi Andy,
I get the same error when installing on Umbraco 7.2.7. We will look into the cause of this.
I have installed version 6.8.2 of uCommerce on Umbraco 7.2.8 without problems.
Is it possible for you to use Umbraco 7.2.8?
Sorry for the inconvenience!
Kind regards, Jesper